# Java Netbeans For loop error: cannot find symbol class, <identifier> expected?

Tags: java, for-loop, netbeans

I'm making a hangman game and this is my current code:

```
//Declaring the array
    String [] WordList = {"anonymous", "tolerate", "appreciation", "commissioner", "harm", "flexibility", "instructional", "scramble", "casino", "tumor"};

// Getting a random word for the game
int num = ((int)Math.ceil(Math.random()*(WordList.length)));
String word = WordList[num];

// The puzzle to be displayed for the user to guess
int letters = word.length();
String hiddenWord = "";
for (int i=0; i<letters; i++){
    hiddenWord+="-";
}
```

At the for loop, I get an error saying 'illegal start of type, cannot find symbol: class i'. 'i' is supposed to be an integer, which I've already declared, so I'm not sure why it's asking for a class. 
There's also another error saying, 'identifier expected' and that there's a missing >. As my < is meant to be used as comparison (and not as a declaration or identifier), I don't understand this error.

For clarification, I should add that this is a desktop application in netbeans. The code is located after the line:

```
public class HangmanGameView extends FrameView {
```

Most of the rest of my code will be located within the actionPerformed code for my buttons. I need to be able to access the word and hiddenWord variables from within the code for the buttons, which is why I've put them here. I'm not positive if that's the problem as of yet. I'm also not sure where to put the code otherwise; there is no main method as far as I can see.

Edit: I hadn't posted the complete code because this is all I've done for now; the rest is all auto-generated by NetBeans, and I thought it wouldn't be relevant. But here it is:

```
/*
 * HangmanGameView.java
 */

package hangmangame;

import org.jdesktop.application.Action;
import org.jdesktop.application.ResourceMap;
import org.jdesktop.application.SingleFrameApplication;
import org.jdesktop.application.FrameView;
import org.jdesktop.application.TaskMonitor;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.Icon;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

/**
 * The application's main frame.
 */
public class HangmanGameView extends FrameView {

//Declaring the array
String [] WordList = {"anonymous", "tolerate", "appreciation", "commissioner", "harm", "flexibility", "instructional", "scramble", "casino", "tumor"};

// Getting a random word for the game
int num = ((int)Math.ceil(Math.random()*(WordList.length)));
String word = WordList[num];

// The puzzle to be displayed for the user to guess
int letters = word.length();
String hiddenWord = "";
for (int i=0; i<letters; i++){
    hiddenWord+="-";
}


public HangmanGameView(SingleFrameApplication app) {

    super(app);

    initComponents();

    // status bar initialization - message timeout, idle icon and busy animation, etc
    ResourceMap resourceMap = getResourceMap();
    int messageTimeout = resourceMap.getInteger("StatusBar.messageTimeout");
    messageTimer = new Timer(messageTimeout, new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            statusMessageLabel.setText("");
        }
    });
    messageTimer.setRepeats(false);
    int busyAnimationRate = resourceMap.getInteger("StatusBar.busyAnimationRate");
    for (int i = 0; i < busyIcons.length; i++) {
        busyIcons[i] = resourceMap.getIcon("StatusBar.busyIcons[" + i + "]");
    }
    busyIconTimer = new Timer(busyAnimationRate, new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            busyIconIndex = (busyIconIndex + 1) % busyIcons.length;
            statusAnimationLabel.setIcon(busyIcons[busyIconIndex]);
        }
    });
    idleIcon = resourceMap.getIcon("StatusBar.idleIcon");
    statusAnimationLabel.setIcon(idleIcon);
    progressBar.setVisible(false);

    // connecting action tasks to status bar via TaskMonitor
    TaskMonitor taskMonitor = new TaskMonitor(getApplication().getContext());
    taskMonitor.addPropertyChangeListener(new java.beans.PropertyChangeListener() {
        public void propertyChange(java.beans.PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
            String propertyName = evt.getPropertyName();
            if ("started".equals(propertyName)) {
                if (!busyIconTimer.isRunning()) {
                    statusAnimationLabel.setIcon(busyIcons[0]);
                    busyIconIndex = 0;
                    busyIconTimer.start();
                }
                progressBar.setVisible(true);
                progressBar.setIndeterminate(true);
            } else if ("done".equals(propertyName)) {
                busyIconTimer.stop();
                statusAnimationLabel.setIcon(idleIcon);
                progressBar.setVisible(false);
                progressBar.setValue(0);
            } else if ("message".equals(propertyName)) {
                String text = (String)(evt.getNewValue());
                statusMessageLabel.setText((text == null) ? "" : text);
                messageTimer.restart();
            } else if ("progress".equals(propertyName)) {
                int value = (Integer)(evt.getNewValue());
                progressBar.setVisible(true);
                progressBar.setIndeterminate(false);
                progressBar.setValue(value);
            }
        }
    });
}

@Action
public void showAboutBox() {
    if (aboutBox == null) {
        JFrame mainFrame = HangmanGameApp.getApplication().getMainFrame();
        aboutBox = new HangmanGameAboutBox(mainFrame);
        aboutBox.setLocationRelativeTo(mainFrame);
    }
    HangmanGameApp.getApplication().show(aboutBox);
}

/** This method is called from within the constructor to
 * initialize the form.
 * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is
 * always regenerated by the Form Editor.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">
private void initComponents() {

    mainPanel = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    titleLabel = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    startButton = new javax.swing.JButton();
    guesswordOutput = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    guessLabel = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    guessInput = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    guessButton = new javax.swing.JButton();
    picLabel = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
    gameOutput = new javax.swing.JTextArea();
    menuBar = new javax.swing.JMenuBar();
    javax.swing.JMenu fileMenu = new javax.swing.JMenu();
    javax.swing.JMenuItem exitMenuItem = new javax.swing.JMenuItem();
    javax.swing.JMenu helpMenu = new javax.swing.JMenu();
    javax.swing.JMenuItem aboutMenuItem = new javax.swing.JMenuItem();
    statusPanel = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    javax.swing.JSeparator statusPanelSeparator = new javax.swing.JSeparator();
    statusMessageLabel = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    statusAnimationLabel = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    progressBar = new javax.swing.JProgressBar();

    org.jdesktop.application.ResourceMap resourceMap = org.jdesktop.application.Application.getInstance(hangmangame.HangmanGameApp.class).getContext().getResourceMap(HangmanGameView.class);
    mainPanel.setBackground(resourceMap.getColor("mainPanel.background")); // NOI18N
    mainPanel.setName("mainPanel"); // NOI18N

    titleLabel.setFont(titleLabel.getFont().deriveFont(titleLabel.getFont().getSize()+19f));
    titleLabel.setForeground(resourceMap.getColor("titleLabel.foreground")); // NOI18N
    titleLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
    titleLabel.setText(resourceMap.getString("titleLabel.text")); // NOI18N
    titleLabel.setName("titleLabel"); // NOI18N

    startButton.setFont(startButton.getFont().deriveFont(startButton.getFont().getStyle() & ~java.awt.Font.BOLD, startButton.getFont().getSize()+5));
    startButton.setForeground(resourceMap.getColor("startButton.foreground")); // NOI18N
    startButton.setText(resourceMap.getString("startButton.text")); // NOI18N
    startButton.setToolTipText(resourceMap.getString("startButton.toolTipText")); // NOI18N
    startButton.setName("startButton"); // NOI18N
    startButton.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            startButtonActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    guesswordOutput.setText(resourceMap.getString("guesswordOutput.text")); // NOI18N
    guesswordOutput.setName("guesswordOutput"); // NOI18N

    guessLabel.setFont(resourceMap.getFont("guessLabel.font")); // NOI18N
    guessLabel.setText(resourceMap.getString("guessLabel.text")); // NOI18N
    guessLabel.setName("guessLabel"); // NOI18N

    guessInput.setBackground(resourceMap.getColor("guessInput.background")); // NOI18N
    guessInput.setFont(resourceMap.getFont("guessInput.font")); // NOI18N
    guessInput.setText(resourceMap.getString("guessInput.text")); // NOI18N
    guessInput.setToolTipText(resourceMap.getString("guessInput.toolTipText")); // NOI18N
    guessInput.setName("guessInput"); // NOI18N

    guessButton.setFont(resourceMap.getFont("guessButton.font")); // NOI18N
    guessButton.setForeground(resourceMap.getColor("guessButton.foreground")); // NOI18N
    guessButton.setText(resourceMap.getString("guessButton.text")); // NOI18N
    guessButton.setName("guessButton"); // NOI18N
    guessButton.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            guessButtonActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    picLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
    picLabel.setIcon(resourceMap.getIcon("picLabel.icon")); // NOI18N
    picLabel.setText(resourceMap.getString("picLabel.text")); // NOI18N
    picLabel.setName("picLabel"); // NOI18N

    jScrollPane1.setName("jScrollPane1"); // NOI18N

    gameOutput.setBackground(resourceMap.getColor("gameOutput.background")); // NOI18N
    gameOutput.setColumns(20);
    gameOutput.setRows(5);
    gameOutput.setName("gameOutput"); // NOI18N
    jScrollPane1.setViewportView(gameOutput);

    javax.swing.GroupLayout mainPanelLayout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(mainPanel);
    mainPanel.setLayout(mainPanelLayout);
    mainPanelLayout.setHorizontalGroup(
        mainPanelLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addComponent(titleLabel, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 485, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        .addGroup(mainPanelLayout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(42, 42, 42)
            .addGroup(mainPanelLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, false)
                .addGroup(mainPanelLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(picLabel, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 150, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGroup(mainPanelLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addComponent(guessLabel, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 182, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                    .addComponent(guessInput, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 73, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addGap(46, 46, 46)
                    .addComponent(guessButton)))
            .addContainerGap(55, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        .addGroup(mainPanelLayout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(181, 181, 181)
            .addComponent(startButton, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addContainerGap(189, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        .addComponent(guesswordOutput, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 485, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );
    mainPanelLayout.setVerticalGroup(
        mainPanelLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(mainPanelLayout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(21, 21, 21)
            .addComponent(titleLabel, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 40, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addGap(18, 18, 18)
            .addComponent(startButton, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addGap(26, 26, 26)
            .addComponent(guesswordOutput, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 35, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addGap(38, 38, 38)
            .addGroup(mainPanelLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(guessLabel)
                .addComponent(guessButton)
                .addComponent(guessInput, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 45, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addGroup(mainPanelLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                .addComponent(jScrollPane1)
                .addComponent(picLabel, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 200, Short.MAX_VALUE))
            .addGap(39, 39, 39))
    );

    menuBar.setName("menuBar"); // NOI18N

    fileMenu.setText(resourceMap.getString("fileMenu.text")); // NOI18N
    fileMenu.setName("fileMenu"); // NOI18N

    javax.swing.ActionMap actionMap = org.jdesktop.application.Application.getInstance(hangmangame.HangmanGameApp.class).getContext().getActionMap(HangmanGameView.class, this);
    exitMenuItem.setAction(actionMap.get("quit")); // NOI18N
    exitMenuItem.setName("exitMenuItem"); // NOI18N
    fileMenu.add(exitMenuItem);

    menuBar.add(fileMenu);

    helpMenu.setText(resourceMap.getString("helpMenu.text")); // NOI18N
    helpMenu.setName("helpMenu"); // NOI18N

    aboutMenuItem.setAction(actionMap.get("showAboutBox")); // NOI18N
    aboutMenuItem.setName("aboutMenuItem"); // NOI18N
    helpMenu.add(aboutMenuItem);

    menuBar.add(helpMenu);

    statusPanel.setName("statusPanel"); // NOI18N

    statusPanelSeparator.setName("statusPanelSeparator"); // NOI18N

    statusMessageLabel.setName("statusMessageLabel"); // NOI18N

    statusAnimationLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.LEFT);
    statusAnimationLabel.setName("statusAnimationLabel"); // NOI18N

    progressBar.setName("progressBar"); // NOI18N

    javax.swing.GroupLayout statusPanelLayout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(statusPanel);
    statusPanel.setLayout(statusPanelLayout);
    statusPanelLayout.setHorizontalGroup(
        statusPanelLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addComponent(statusPanelSeparator, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 485, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        .addGroup(statusPanelLayout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addComponent(statusMessageLabel)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 315, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addComponent(progressBar, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addComponent(statusAnimationLabel)
            .addContainerGap())
    );
    statusPanelLayout.setVerticalGroup(
        statusPanelLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(statusPanelLayout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addComponent(statusPanelSeparator, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addGroup(statusPanelLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(statusMessageLabel)
                .addComponent(statusAnimationLabel)
                .addComponent(progressBar, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addGap(3, 3, 3))
    );

    setComponent(mainPanel);
    setMenuBar(menuBar);
    setStatusBar(statusPanel);
}// </editor-fold>

private void startButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    // Initializes the game and displays the empty word for the player

}

private void guessButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    // TODO add your handling code here:
}

// Variables declaration - do not modify
private javax.swing.JTextArea gameOutput;
private javax.swing.JButton guessButton;
private javax.swing.JTextField guessInput;
private javax.swing.JLabel guessLabel;
private javax.swing.JLabel guesswordOutput;
private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
private javax.swing.JPanel mainPanel;
private javax.swing.JMenuBar menuBar;
private javax.swing.JLabel picLabel;
private javax.swing.JProgressBar progressBar;
private javax.swing.JButton startButton;
private javax.swing.JLabel statusAnimationLabel;
private javax.swing.JLabel statusMessageLabel;
private javax.swing.JPanel statusPanel;
private javax.swing.JLabel titleLabel;
// End of variables declaration

private final Timer messageTimer;
private final Timer busyIconTimer;
private final Icon idleIcon;
private final Icon[] busyIcons = new Icon[15];
private int busyIconIndex = 0;

private JDialog aboutBox;
}
```

Final Edit:
I moved my for loop to inside the start button code - leaving the initial declaration of the hiddenWord string at the beginning - and it's working fine now. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Please post the **complete** code (btw: the problem has nothing to do with NetBeans - it's plain Java question)

Comment: You can't put statements bare in a class like that.  Put your code inside a method or initializer block.

Comment: If I put the code inside a method, how would I declare it, and how would I call the method, so that I can draw the variables from the method when I need them for use by the buttons? I've experimented with methods but I always end up getting errors. Thanks for the help btw

Comment: Use the classes constructor to do any declarations and initializations. Then from your main method call class.method()...